# Makefiles in iOS build using jenkins

Tags: ios, jenkins, makefile

I'm new to makefiles and jenkins.Is there any guide on how to write makefile to run build and the unit test together using jenkins.?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use Makefiles to build and run both your application/library and tests.

Here is a good guide to Makefiles:

```
http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/
```

It should help you with writing a simple makefile. For more information, Google is your friend.

Another good guide is here:

```
http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html
```

Remember, jenkins and makefiles are completely unrelated. You can use Jenkins with makefiles, and use makefiles without jenkins. One is a continuous integration system, the other just another way of building your software.

You can go ahead and use Xserver as suggested in the other post, but Jenkins has advantages that many other systems don't: it is extensible using a whole host of plugins, has a large user and developer community and is used for multiple types and styles of projects in various languages. While your project is purely for iOS, there are other things in Jenkins you could take advantage of from the available plugins list.

Comment: (Thanks to whoever voted down. A reason why would have been great.)

Answer (score 0):

There is an XCode plugin:

> `https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin`

Maybe this helps too:

> http://programming.oreilly.com/2013/04/upward-mobility-automating-ios-builds-with-jenkins.html

But maybe you are better off using Xserver if you try to do continuos integration:

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/200-Adopting_a_Continuous_Integration_Workflow/adopt_continuous_integration.html